# Decoding JSON with struct returns nil

Tags: swift

I am trying to learn requests to an API. I am using News API to test. I have two structs and a WebService function.

I have no idea what could be wrong here, as I am following a tutorial to learn this, and doing exactly what the teacher is showing me to do.

Struct:

```
import Foundation

struct ArticleList: Decodable {
    let status: String
    let articles: [Article]
}

struct Article: Decodable { // Decodable because we only read, we do not send anything with this struct
    let title: String
    let description: String
}
```

Here is the WebService:

```
import Foundation

class Webservice {
    
    func getArticles(url: URL, completion: @escaping ([Article]?) -> ()) {
        
        print("URL: \(url)")
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                completion(nil)
            } else if let data = data {
                
                let articleList = try? JSONDecoder().decode(ArticleList.self, from: data)
            
                
                if let articleList = articleList {
                    completion(articleList.articles)
                }
                
                print(articleList?.articles)
            }
        }.resume()
        
    }
    
}
```

The last print in the WebService class is printing `nil` even though I am using the News API link: `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&apiKey=XX` and yes I am using an apiKey instead of XX and when I visit the link, I get the json so that should not be the problem.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Don’t use “try?” Use “do try catch” with “print(error)” in the catch

Comment: NEVER use `try?` (with a question mark) unless you can debug it. Use a proper `do`/`try`/`catch`.

Comment: Alright, did not know that - thanks guys! I get this error now: ```The data couldn’t be read because it is missing.```

Comment: Are you using “print(error)” and not some other variation. You should also remove the localized description part of the print you have already.

Comment: @loremipsum if I remove the localized part, this is the error I get: ```valueNotFound(Swift.String, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "articles", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 14", intValue: 14), CodingKeys(stringValue: "description", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected String value but found null instead.", underlyingError: nil))```

Comment: Change `let description: String` to `let description: String?`

Comment: @loremipsum that did it - thank you. How could you know that from the error? Because of ```debugDescription```?

Comment: It is right there `CodingKeys(stringValue: "description", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected String value but found null instead.", underlyingError: nil))` just FYI whatever tutorial you are following is not that great. I would look for another. Errors. should never be ignored and you are doing that in many places with this little bit of code. Always handle gracefully and make sure th user knows what is going on.

Comment: @loremipsum that makes sense. Thank you for helping me. I actually paid for that tutorial, to learn the MVVM pattern so that is kind of messed up haha...

Comment: Get your money back if you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never use

```
try?
```

It is ignoring errors, use

```
do{
    //Your code here
}catch{
    print(error)
}
```

`CodingKeys(stringValue: "description", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected String value but found null instead.", underlyingError: nil))` is telling you that it found `null` therefore...

Change `let description: String` to `let description: String?`

To make it optional, the API will not always have a value for the `description`.

Errors should always be handled gracefully. You should identify a way to `throw` or return a `Result` with a `failure`.

The user should be told if there is an issue.