# How do I make a JSON API Call for Widgets in Swift?

Tags: swift, swiftui, widget

I have been following a tutorial linked [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tjiWNdZG-aU&t=303s). It also uses a JSON API, but when I tried to adapt it to my API the data does not load in my simulator. My API returns a call like this and I'm just trying to extract "rates":

```
{
    "data": {
        "success": true,
        "fluctuation": true,
        "start_date": "2022-10-22",
        "end_date": "2022-11-22",
        "base": "RICE",
        "rates": {
            "USD": {
                "start_rate": 16.410000000000014,
                "end_rate": 17.920000000000137,
                "change": 1.5100000000001224,
                "change_pct": 9.201706276661309
            }
        },
        "unit": "per cwt"
    }
}
```

I adapted the structs and made the timeline change as shown here. And I changed the TimeLine provider too. I think the initialization should be fine as I'm treating it like regular JSON in an API call but I'm not receiving anything back. I tried with the same code as in the tutorial and it worked, I'm not sure what is wrong.

```
struct Rice: TimelineEntry, Codable {
    var date: Date = .init()
    var data: DataClass = DataClass(rates: Rates(usd: Usd(startRate: 0.0, endRate: 0.0, change: 0.0, changePct: 0.0)))
}

struct DataClass: Codable {
    var rates: Rates

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case rates
    }
}

struct Rates: Codable {
    var usd: Usd

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case usd = "USD"
    }
}

struct Usd: Codable {
    var startRate: Double
    var endRate: Double
    var change: Double
    var changePct: Double

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case startRate = "start_rate"
        case endRate = "end_rate"
        case change
        case changePct = "change_pct"
    }
}

struct Provider: TimelineProvider {
    func placeholder(in context: Context) -> Rice {Rice(date: Date())}

    func getSnapshot(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Rice) -> ()) {
        let entry = Rice(date: Date())
        completion(entry)
}

    func getTimeline(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> ()) {
       let currentDate = Date()
        Task {
            if var riceData = try? await fetchData() {
                riceData.date = currentDate
                let nextUpdate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day,value: 1, to: currentDate)!
                let timeline = Timeline(entries: [riceData], policy: .after(nextUpdate))
                completion(timeline)
            }
        }
        
    }
    func fetchData()async throws->Rice {
        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
        let response = try await session.data(from: URL(string: APIURL)!)
        let riceData = try JSONDecoder().decode([Rice].self, from: response.0)
        if let rice = riceData.first {
            return rice
        }
        return .init()
    }
}
fileprivate let APIURL = "https://commodities-api.com/api/fluctuation?access_key=z9075xu0tihtz55dgq56forsl1f1vgnawbvjs1qohsi7ujr8x4pax14o2b8h&base=RICE&symbols=USD&start_date=2022-10-22&end_date=2022-11-22"
```

Comment: Don't use `try? await` for the async call.  Use `do ... catch` around your try statement to capture any errors as they will likely tell you what's wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Decoding JSON with struct returns nil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74256380/decoding-json-with-struct-returns-nil)