# WeatherKit call returning default response

Tags: ios, swift, weatherkit

I'm trying to use WeatherKit to just get a simple weather forecast for a location.

```
do {
    let location = CLLocation(latitude: 37.3346, longitude: -122.0087)
    let weather = try await WeatherService().weather(for: location)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

When I run this on a physical device, I get an empty Weather object and the following in the console:

```
[WeatherDataService] Response did not contain requested dataset: .appLocationConfig. Returning default value: AppLocationConfig(reportAnIssue: ReportIssueLocationConfig(position: beforeFooter, minDaysSinceInteraction: 0), expireTime: 2022-11-27 04:31:20 +0000
```

Xcode is managing my provisioning profile, I've added the WeatherKit capability, and I have an active Apple Developer Program membership, so I don't think I should be having any problems accessing WeatherKit. What's going on, and how can I fix it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74256380/decoding-json-with-struct-returns-nil/74256559#74256559

Comment: Have you followed **all** of the steps listed in Apple's sample app for WeatherKit? See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/weatherkit/fetching_weather_forecasts_with_weatherkit

Comment: Are you facing this on a simulator, or on a device?

Comment: @HangarRash Yes, I have

Comment: @AbhinavMathur On a device, although it doesn't work on a simulator either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether you consider this a fix to the issue or not, adding the `including` parameter to the call fixed the issue for me.

So instead of

```swift
let weather = try await WeatherService().weather(for: location)
```

You can call

```swift
let weather = try await WeatherService().weather(for: location, including: .current)
```

It should return you the same information as the original call.