# Swift Data Model from JSON Response

Tags: json, swift, codable

I am running into an issue building the correct data model for the following JSON response.

```
{
  "resources": [
    {
      "courseid": 4803,
      "color": "Blue",
      "teeboxtype": "Championship",
      "slope": 121,
      "rating": 71.4
    },
    {
      "courseid": 4803,
      "color": "White",
      "teeboxtype": "Men's",
      "slope": 120,
      "rating": 69.6
    },
    {
      "courseid": 4803,
      "color": "Red",
      "teeboxtype": "Women's",
      "slope": 118,
      "rating": 71.2
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is the current model.  No matter what I do I can't seem to get the model populated.  Here is also my URL session retrieving the data.  I am new to Swift and SwiftUI so please be gentle. I am getting data back however I am missing something.

```
import Foundation

struct RatingsResources: Codable {
    let golfcourserating : [GolfCourseRating]?
}
    
    struct GolfCourseRating: Codable {
        let id: UUID = UUID()
        let courseID: Int?
        let teeColor: String?
        let teeboxtype: String?
        let teeslope: Double?
        let teerating: Double?
        
        enum CodingKeysRatings: String, CodingKey {
            case courseID = "courseid"
            case teeColor = "color"
            case teeboxtype
            case teeslope = "slope"
            case teerating = "rating"
        }
    }

    func getCoureRating(courseID: String?) {
       let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore (value: 0)
       
       print("GETTING COURSE TEE RATINGS..........")
       
       let urlString: String = "https://api.golfbert.com/v1/courses/\(courseID ?? "4800")/teeboxes"
       
       print ("API STRING: \(urlString) ")
       
       let url = URLComponents(string: urlString)!
       let request = URLRequest(url: url.url!).signed
       let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
       let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            
            guard let data = data else {
                print(String(describing: error))
                semaphore.signal()
                return
            }
           
               if let response = try? JSONDecoder().decode([RatingsResources].self, from: data) {
                   DispatchQueue.main.async {
                       self.ratingresources = response
                   }
                   return
               }

           print("*******Data String***********")
           print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)
           print("***************************")
           
           let ratingsData: RatingsResources = try! decoder.decode(RatingsResources.self, from: data)
           
           print("Resources count \(ratingsData.golfcourserating?.count)")
           
             semaphore.signal()
           }

           task.resume()
           semaphore.wait()
           
   } //: END OF GET COURSE SCORECARD
```

Comment: The enum should be called `CodingKeys`, not `CodingKeysRatings` (otherwise it won't be found by decoder)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Decoding JSON with struct returns nil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74256380/decoding-json-with-struct-returns-nil)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, never use `try?` while decoding your `JSON`. This will hide all errors from you. Use `try` and an appropriate `do/catch` block. In the `catch` block at least print the `error`.

Looking at your model there seem to be three issues here.

- You don´t have an array of `RatingsResources` in your array. It is just a single instance.

  ```
  let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(RatingsResources.self, from: data)
  ```
- `RatingsResources` is not implemented correct.

  ```
  let golfcourserating : [GolfCourseRating]?
  ```

  should be:

  ```
  let resources: [GolfCourseRating]?
  ```
- Your coding keys are implemented wrong instead of:

  ```
  enum CodingKeysRatings: String, CodingKey {
  ```

  it should read:

  ```
  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
  ```

Comment: "First of all, never use try? while decoding your JSON." -- this is an opinion, not the rule. Also like I stated above, I think main issue is `CodingKeys`

Comment: @akjndklskver not only `CodingKeys`. Even with the wrong named `CodingKeys` the values should have been `nil` as they are optional. Regarding my suggestion of never use try?. I stand by that. It is bad practice in any case. Especially if you are pulling remote stuff. You never know what data will arive. And hidding the error will give you a hard time finding out what happend.

Comment: You didn't mention `CodingKeys` at all in your original answer, this is why I pointed it out. I'm glad you edited your answer after seeing my comment.

Comment: Try / catch vs `try?`: this is still your opinion. Hence it should not be presented as "never use" or "bad practice" -- as established by whom? Apple never says don't do it, so why not? I see lots of cases where catch is only done to send error to os_log (or even worse: print it out). It's ok to do that on debug, but on production build - its a waste. It's no better than "hiding the error". So if you don't have any intention to do anything with the error (e.g. send it to crashalitics), `try?` is better.

Comment: @akjndklskver You may be right in a more general context. But, I wrote my answer specific to encoding `JSON` from a remote source. And regarding to this scenario this may not be a rule implemented by Apple, but it should be a (at least personal) rule everyone dealing with this stuff should follow.

Comment: While not using `try?` is not a *rule*, the simple fact is that about 95% of Codable questions would not need to be asked if people used `do/try/catch` and printed the `error` rather than `try ?`. At the very least their question would include a meaningful error message. Unfortunately the boilerplate at app.quicktype.io shows the use of `try ?` and so people end up wasting time.

Answer (score 0):

You should add enum CodingKey with `resources` at struct `RatingsResources`

And decode:

```
if let response = try? JSONDecoder().decode(RatingsResources.self, from: data) {
  // Your response handler
}
```